# logrotate directory containing log files

Tags: linux, unix, logrotate

I am looking for a way that I can logrotate all the log files in a specific directory.

The config that I am currently using is:

```
/path/to/folder/*.log {
daily
rotate 5
missingok
notifempty
maxage 14
compress
```

}

daily - since I want it to run everyday

rotate - rotate 5 versions before deletion

maxage 14 - delete actual log files after 14 days

compress - compress the log files on rotating.

What I don't understand is why are the current days log files also getting compressed? I want atleast current days and yesterdays log files to remain untouched.

I tried using `delaycompress` but that didn't help either.

Can you please help what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `delaycompress` will delay compression by one rotation.

You should then have:

- The current log file to which is being written;
- The previous log file uncompressed (created from the "current" logfile just before the rotation);
- Earlier log files compressed.

Do note that `maxage 14` is not really usefull here as `rotate` will delete a logfile after 5 (daily) rotations.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more regarding the current log file and previous log file uncompressed? In my case I have several log files per day, each unique for a process. And that is why I do not wish to compress them. Also, thanks for pointing out the maxage.I realized that it is not effective since I have rotate 5. Thank you

Comment: In my experience the log rotation rules are applied to each matched file.
So if you have "PROC1232.log" and you rotate it with delaycompress, it is renamed to "PROC1232.log.1" and previous logs starting with "PROC1232.log." are compressed.  The file "PROC1232.log" will be created if a new process creates it.
If you want the file "PROC1232.log" to be created on log rotation, you need to add `create`